# Alter the behavior of Throwable.printStackTrace() under a custom Thread?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace, minecraft

Currently I'm making a mod for Vanilla Minecraft server, which I'm not able to modify the underlying code. Now I'm trying to alter the stack trace printed when I accidentally run into a bug with the re-obfuscated version (attached to the server.jar file downloaded directly from the official Mojang site), making it "deobfuscated", like what Minecraft Forge does. (I've tried finding what I need in the source of Forge, but I guess I'm not experienced enough to read it. :<)

Since the exceptions and the stack traces are sometimes thrown and printed by the server codes which I can't modify, I guess using custom `Exception` file may not help at all.

I've tried to run the main method using a custom `Thread` with custom `getStackTrace()` method, which of course doesn't work at all, since the stack trace generation is implemented in the native codes of the JVM.

The codes below are some examples:

Main.java (Cannot be modified and will be renamed during re-obfuscation)

```
package underlying.cannot.be.modified

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ...
        new SomeClass().someMethod();
        ...
    }
}
```

SomeClass.java (Cannot be modified and will be renamed during re-obfuscation)

```
package underlying.cannot.be.modified

public class SomeClass
{
    ...

    public void someMethod()
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            /*
             * An example of an exception thrown in the underlying codes
             * which cannot be modified.
             */
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

For instance, the following obfuscation mapping is applied:

```
underlying.cannot.be.modified.Main -> underlying.cannot.be.modified.Main
  main(String[]) -> main
underlying.cannot.be.modified.SomeClass -> A
  someMethod() -> a
```

and a stack trace may be like:

```
at A.a (?:?)
at underlying.cannot.be.modified.Main (?:?)
```

I'd like to make the stack trace printed as:

```
at underlying.cannot.be.modified.SomeClass.someMethod (?:?)
at underlying.cannot.be.modified.Main (?:?)
```

(Of course I hold the mapping which I can implement into my code, and the `main()` method above is called by my custom code instead of called by the JVM directly. :>)

Does anyone know how to modify the behavior of the `getStackTrace()` method, by either Java codes, reflection, or even through the custom native codes, with the least required external libraries possible? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest calling method `getStackTrace` instead of `printStackTrace` and generate your own printout of the stack trace.

Comment: Ummm...

I'm not being offensive. I guess I didn't say it clearly enough. The example codes above are given as not modifiable, meaning that I can't change the `printStackTrace()` to `getStackTrace()`. Thanks for your answer, but sorry for rejecting it. :I

Comment: I have no experience in using it, but it sounds to me that it may be what you require, so in case you are unaware of its existence, take a look at the Byte Code Engineering Library (Apache Commons BCEL)

Comment: I guess I'll give it a try. Thanks Abra! :>